# I want to remove/hide the toolbar from mui DataTable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there anyway I can remove or hide the toolbar present in the top right corner of Mui Data tables??

Comment: Please include your code so far. And do you mean the Table component? or DataGrid? The documentation doesn't seem to include a "DataTable".

Comment: I solve the issue by using Data grid, actually Data Table does not have option to customize